# How to get related product collection in block

Tags: magento2, blocks, product-collection, related-products

I use this way to get related product collection

```
/**
 * Prepare and return product collection
 *
 * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection
 */
public function createCollection()
{
    /** @var $collection \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection */
    $myBlock = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('AntonStudio\StockUpdate\Block\RelatedProducts');

    $currentProduct = $myBlock->getCurrentProduct();
    $relatedProducts = $currentProduct->getRelatedProductCollection();
    /**
     * Prevent retrieval of duplicate records. This may occur when multiselect product attribute matches
     * several allowed values from condition simultaneously
     */
    $relatedProducts->distinct(true);

    return $relatedProducts;
}
```

and used it in template

```
<?php if ( $exist = ( $block->getProductCollection() && $block->getProductCollection()->getSize() ) ): ?>
    <?php
    $type = 'widget-product-grid';

    $mode = 'grid';

    $image = 'new_products_content_widget_grid';
    $items = $block->getProductCollection()->getItems();

    $showWishlist = true;
    $showCompare  = true;
    $showCart     = true;
    $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::DEFAULT_VIEW;
    $description  = false;

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

    $_helper      = $this->helper( 'Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output' );
    $_imagehelper = $this->helper( 'Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image' );
    ?>

    <div class="block widget block-products-list <?= /* @noEscape */
    $mode ?>">
        <?php if ( $block->getTitle() ): ?>
            <div class="block-title">
                <strong><?= $block->escapeHtml( __( $block->getTitle() ) ) ?></strong>
            </div>
        <?php endif ?>
        <div class="block-content">
            <?= /* @noEscape */
            '<!-- ' . $image . '-->' ?>
            <div class="home-products-<?= /* @noEscape */
            $mode ?> <?= /* @noEscape */
            $mode ?>">
                <ol class="home-product-items <?= /* @noEscape */
                $type ?>">
                    <?php $iterator = 1; ?>
                    <?php foreach ( $items as $_item ): ?>
                        <?php
                        $_product = $objectManager->get( 'Magento\Catalog\Model\Product' )->load( $_item->getId() );
                        $all_data = $_product->getData();

                        $imageUrl = $_imagehelper->init( $_item, 'product_thumbnail_image' )->resize(300, 300)->getUrl();
                        ?>

                        <?= /* @noEscape */
                    ( $iterator ++ == 1 ) ? '<li class="product-item">' : '</li><li class="product-item">' ?>

                        <div class="ProductListItem">
                            <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getProductUrl($_item)) ?>" class="ProductListItem__imageWrap">
                                <img src="<?= $imageUrl ?>"
                                     class="ProductListItem__productImage">
                            </a>
                            <div class="ProductListItem__summaryWrap">
<!--                                <div class="ProductListItem__productSize">--><?//= isset($all_data['tile_length_mm'])?$all_data['tile_length_mm']:'' . ' * ' . isset($all_data['tile_width_mm'])?$all_data['tile_width_mm']:'' ?><!--</div>-->
                                <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getProductUrl($_item)) ?>" class="ProductListItem__productTitle">title<?= $block->escapeHtml( $_item->getName() ) ?></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ProductListItem__addToCartWrap">
                                <div class="ProductListItem__price">
                                    <?= $block->getProductPriceHtml( $_item, $type ) ?>/M2
                                </div>
                                <div class="ProductListItem__addToCartIcon">
                                    <?php if ($this->helper('Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data')->isAllow() && $showWishlist): ?>
                                        <a href="#"
                                           data-post='<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getAddToWishlistParams($_item) ?>' class="action towishlist" data-action="add-to-wishlist" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Add to Wish List')) ?>">
                                            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Wish List')) ?></span>
                                        </a>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?= ( $iterator == count( $items ) + 1 ) ? '</li>' : '' ?>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                </ol>
            </div>
            <?= $block->getPagerHtml() ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But `$block->escapeHtml( $_item->getName() )` out put null

Comment: Is it helpful for you?

Comment: Check the article with details, https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/related-products-collection-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 0):

Use this below code in your block :

```
protected $_productFactory;
protected $_registry;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    array $data = []
)
{
    $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
    $this->_registry = $registry;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

public function createCollection()
{
    $product = $this->_productFactory->create()->load($productId);
    //$product = $this->_registry->registry('current_product'); // For current product
    $relatedProducts = $product->getRelatedProducts();

    return $relatedProducts;
}
```

And use this below code in your phtml :

```
if (!empty($block->createCollection())) {
    echo 'Related Products <br />';
    $productFactory = $this->_productFactory->create();
    foreach ($block->createCollection() as $relatedProduct) {
        $_product = $productFactory->load($relatedProduct->getId());
        echo $relatedProduct->getId().'-->'.$_product->getPrice().'-->'.$_product->getName().'-->'.$relatedProduct->getId(); //get name
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Prepare and return product collection
 *
 * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection
 */
public function createCollection()
{
    /** @var $collection \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection */
    $myBlock = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('AntonStudio\StockUpdate\Block\RelatedProducts');

    $currentProduct = $myBlock->getCurrentProduct();
    $relatedProducts = $currentProduct->getRelatedProducts();
    /**
     * Prevent retrieval of duplicate records. This may occur when multiselect product attribute matches
     * several allowed values from condition simultaneously
     */
    $relatedProducts->distinct(true);

    return $relatedProducts;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the model file for this

```
<?php
namespace Companyname\Vendorname\Model;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;

class RelatedProductList
{
    protected $productRepositoryInterface;
    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepositoryInterface,
        LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->productRepositoryInterface = $productRepositoryInterface;
    }
    public function getRelatedProductsList()
    {
        $productId = 1;
        $relatedProductIdArray = [];
        try {
            $product = $this->productRepositoryInterface->getById($productId);
            $related = $product->getRelatedProducts();

            if (count($related)) {
                foreach ($related as $item) {
                    $relatedProductIdArray[] = $item->getId();
                }
            }
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            $this->logger->error($exception->getMessage());
        }

        return $relatedProductIdArray;
    }
}
```